# Using pointers to replace char in char array

Tags: c

Simple programming just replaces a letter in a char array trying to learn pointers. Not sure what the problem is, I simply get the output "senrence"
maybe I declared a string literal or is my pointer logic wrong?

```
void replace(char *s,char *ptr_r,char *ptr_t);

int main()

{

    char s[] = "senrence";
    char ch ='r';
    char replacer = 't';
    char *ptr_r = &ch;
    char *ptr_t = &replacer;

    replace(s,ptr_r,ptr_t);

    int i;

    for(i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        printf("%c",s[i]);
    }

    return 0;

}


void replace(char *s,char *ptr_r,char *ptr_t)

{

    char *p;

    for(p=s;*p != '\0';p++)
    {
        if(*p==*ptr_r)
            *(ptr_t) = *(p);
    }

     s= '\0';

}
```

Comment: Try `*p = *ptr_t` in `replace()`.

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much!!

Comment: BTW `s= '\0';` is not necessary (This does not make sense). For `ch` and `replacer`, why do you need to make arguments a pointer?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY you're right it works with just passing them as chars idk I guess I wanted to try using all pointers for practice, also you're correct I don't need the statement with the null character, could you by chance tell me why?

Comment: `s` is a pointer passed as an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assignment is wrong:

```
void replace(char *s,char *ptr_r,char *ptr_t)

{

char *p;

    for(p=s;*p != '\0';p++)
    {
        if(*p==*ptr_r)
            *(p)=*(ptr_t);  //modified line
    }
}
```

**Edit :**

- I've removed the unnecessary `s='\0';`
- You can use `puts(s)` to print `char[]` instead of iterating it
  through loop. Just a suggestion that will save you from writing code
  for loop.
- From the given code, I got that you're trying to learn the concept of
  **pointers**. Hence, I didn't advice you do the same task with `char variables` or `call by value` instead of using `pointers (call by reference)`.

Comment: Can you comment on or correct the other issues as well? Or would you actually write what you wrote?

Comment: Answering your another comment, you don't need s='\0' coz you are not adding any chars in string. You are just replacing the character. So it's not needed.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Anything I've missed?

Comment: Well, surely the comparison and replacement characters should be passed by value. Learning the concept of pointers includes learning what they are for. Another thing: Apart from saying that `p = '\0'` is unnecessary, it is also unusual and misleading; `p = nullptr` would be a better way to null a pointer. Using `'\0'` is not technically incorrect, mind you: "A null pointer constant is an integral constant expression prvalue of integer type that evaluates to zero", and "Types bool, char [...]  are collectively called integral types." It is just a sign and source of confusion.